# Recursive definition with several things wrong

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, recursion, recursive-algorithms

There are several things wrong with the following recursive definition. The function is meant to be valid for all nonnegative integers. Provide me with 3 errors in the following recursive function:

$
  f(a,b) = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    1 & \quad \text{if $b = 0$}\\
    1 & \quad \text{if $b = 1$}\\
    1 & \quad \text{if $b = 2$}\\
    f(b-1, b) & \quad \text{if $20 \ge b \ge 2$} \\
    f(b-4, b-1) & \quad \text{if $b \ge 20$}
  \end{array} \right. 
$

I have come up with four possible errors so far however I am not sure if I am correct

1. I am not really sure if this counts as an error but $a$ in this function is irrelevant, it doesn't add anything to the function
2. when $20 \geq b \geq 2$ = $f(b-1,b)$ $b$ doesn't get incremented or decremented by anything. If you were to write a recursive function in java it would throw a stack overflow error instantly. If you were to change it to $b - 1$ it will work but you will always get one for your answer.
3. Bad base cases for $b = 0 - 2$ as you will only be able to get one as an answer.
4. when $20 \geq b \geq 2$  the  $b \geq 2$ is irreverent because there is already a base case for b = 2

If anyone sees anything else worth noticing or I am wrong about one of my possible errors. Please let me know I am just trying to see the bigger picture here.

Comment: The function is defined with two variables. $a$ is needed because when you need $a = b-1$ to evaluate $f(b-1,b)$

Comment: It is weird because for instance $b = 3$, there is no way to evaluate $f(2,3)$ from the base case for $b=0,1,2$. The recursive definition is missed.

Comment: @UnbelieveTable yes you are right the function is defined with two variables and a is indeed needed for this to work. However there are no base cases for a so wouldn't that make it irrelevant? Its not really doing anything at all in my opinion. This hole function depends on b and a is kinda just there. Do you disagree?

Comment: I think a would be relevant if one of the function calls was multiplied, divided, added or subtracted by a but its not

Comment: No, there are base cases for $a$. For $b=0,1,2$, the function is valued at 1, and it means that for any $a$ as a nonnegative integer, $f(a,0)=f(a,1)=f(a,2)=1$. The actual problem is it doesn't go further to $b=3$.